# Account is in the red

Tags: grammar

The account is in "the" red. The store is bankrupt.

Here why do you say "in the" instead of "in red" without the?

Because it is that specific? Without "the" would it mean entirely different?

Answer (score 1):

It's an established idiom:
[Merriam-Webster "in the red"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20red)

> spending and owing more money than is being earned
> *Apparently the company had been in the red for some time before it went out of business*.

I don't know why the idiom has that exact form instead of "in red".
Also, there's an antonym "in the black", with the same form.

Comment: The reference is to figures written in red ink.  https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/in-the-red.html

Comment: Thanks. Then if I say "in red" without "the", would you perfectly understand?

Comment: @JoeKim Since it's a fixed idiom, if you use "in red", you may not be understood.

Comment: in the red/in the black: standard accounting terminology.